# easyocr installation error when install pillow

Tags: python, pip, easyocr

I'm trying to install the easyocr library, but every time it comes time to install the Pillow library it gives an error.

I've already tried to install pillow alone and install pytorch first, but it keeps giving the same error, if anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Here's the error below:

```
Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Running setup.py install for Pillow did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [179 lines of output]
running install      
running build
running build_py     
creating build      
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10      
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL      
copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL      
copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\PIL
running egg_info
writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-
info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c'
warning: no files found matching '*.h'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

Comment: you can run pip with `--verbose` to see more details in error. And put it in question. Without details we can't help. Maybe it has to compile some C/C++ code and it needs some C/C++ library. Or it needs C/C++ compiler and other tools for compiling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @furas i used `--verbose` but it didn't return anything that makes sense to me

Comment: but full code can make sense for us - but we have to see it. Last line with `zlib` headers means it try to compile some C/C++ code which need files *.h from libraray zlib - but it is not Python module so you can't install it with `pip`. On Linux I would have to install `apt install libzlib-dev` to get these file but on Windows it can make problem. So maybe it would be simpler to install precompiled module from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) - see [pillow](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that i ommit the line of error, but seeing on others foruns the error was caused because i was using the version 3.10 of python when the library Pillow, that was causing the installation error, is only supported for 3.9.12 of olders versions, so to resolve the problem we have to uninstall the actual python version and install the correct python version or create a virtual enviroment with the correct python version (the venv is a hint mine).

Thanks for everyones help and i hope that help others people with similary problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you need to use a Pillow version greater than 8.3 when using Python 3.10

[Pillow Python Support](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#python-support)